# Mouse enter/Mouse leave en C#

Tags: c#

Como le quito el color celeste que trae por defecto el menu al pasar el mouse por una opcion??

[image: Mause enter]

Esto es lo que hice pero no quita el color celeste.

```
private void menuoperario_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filemenu.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 9.75f, FontStyle.Bold);
        requestmenu.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 9.75f, FontStyle.Bold);
        menuoperario.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 12.75f, FontStyle.Bold);
        menuoperario.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
        menuoperario.BackColor = Color.Black;
    }

    private void menuoperario_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filemenu.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 9.75f, FontStyle.Bold);
        requestmenu.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 9.75f, FontStyle.Bold);
        menuoperario.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 9.75f, FontStyle.Bold);
        menuoperario.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        menuoperario.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
```

Comment: Es una aplicación web? o de windows? y que tipo de objeto es?? button?

Comment: windows, es un label

Answer (score 0):

La siguiente **[solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9400099/4092887)** remueve el borde de tu control:

```
menuoperario.TabStop = false;
menuoperario.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
menuoperario.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
menuoperario.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255); //transparente
```

---

> NOTA: Hice pruebas sobre un elemento `Button`. Con el elemento `Label`no tuve problemas con los bordes.